# mongoDB candidates collection make response time faster with 100000 documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, architecture

I have an express.js RESTapi connected to the mongoDB atlas server. In that application, I have a collection called candidates and have 100,000 records on it.

This is the candidate model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const candidateSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  phone: String,
  address: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  zip: String,
  country: String,
  resume: String,
  coverLetter: String,
});

const Candidate = mongoose.model('Candidate', candidateSchema);
module.exports = Candidate;
```

In my login endpoint, I have this code.

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.time("login operation");
    const user = await Candidate.findOne({ email });
    console.timeEnd("login operation");
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Email not found");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send("Invalid password");
    res.send("Logged in");
  } catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

If I pass an email address and execute the line `const user = await Candidate.findOne({ email });` It will take 200ms seconds to return me a response. What are the ways that I can improve this code and reduce response time?

One suggestion is to use indexing. But what is the most suitable type of index for this use-case. there are few index types in the mongoDB.

I know this is a system engineering question and hope a lot of people need to know a complete answer to this. That is why I put this as a question.

Comment: Have you tried creating an index on the field you are searching on? Specifically `{ email: 1}`? The Performance Advisor tab it Atlas may advise something similar